# Django - Query object by last element added to ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-orm

I have something like this:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.ManyToMany(Status)

class Status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    date = models.DateTimeField('Status creation date')
```

How can I query all the cars where their last status (most recent) is `REPAIRED` for instance? Is this achievable in just one query?

Comment: if someone came here to find right answer - it is there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388511/django-orm-construct-query-that-would-look-for-match-on-field-in-object-at-the

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db.models import Max

cars = Car.objects.annotate(Max('status__date')).filter(status__name='REPAIRED').distinct()
```

You may read the [Django examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for Many to Many relationships.

Comment: Does this take into account only the most recent status?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working as expected. By annotating every result with the max date, still I'm not able to determine if the newest is Repaired.

Comment: Switching the order of `annotate` and `filter` should fix that. Updated